# toSVG () does not respect the sources of text and the underline

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, fabricjs

I have a problem.
I add text to the canvas with the following code:

```
var txt = new fabric.Text("Texto de prueba", 
    {
        top:canvas.getHeight()/2,    
        left:canvas.getWidth()/2,
        fontWeight: 'bold' , 
        textDecoration: 'underline' ,  
        fontStyle: 'italic', 
        textColor: '#cccccc', 
        fontFamily: "'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif"
    });
    txt.setFill("#000000");
    canvas.add(txt); 

    canvas.renderAll() ;
```

The web result in canvas:

http://s2.subirimagenes.com/privadas/previo/thump_2114814textoweb.png

Then, I toSVG () the canvas and returns the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="800" height="400" xml:space="preserve"><desc>Created with Fabric.js
1.2.9</desc><defs></defs><g transform="translate(400 200)"><text font-family="''Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif'" font-size="40" font-style="italic" font-weight="bold" text-decoration="underline" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: ; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: #000000; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(-167.5 39)"><tspan x="0" y="-26" fill="#000000">Texto de prueba</tspan></text></g></svg>
```

I save that code in a svg file and open with firefox, the result is:

http://s2.subirimagenes.com/privadas/previo/thump_2114816resultado.png

Obviously, the text font is not the same, and the underline is not appear.

Please, I need help.
should work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works in Chrome.
The problem with text-decoration is a [bug in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=317196)
In Firefox 26.0 text-decoration is working.

The problem with font-family is a bug in fabric.js - as you can see there are too many quotes in font-family (svg output).
Can you please [file a bug on github?](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/new)

Answer (score 1):

Firefox 25 will be the first version that supports underlines on SVG text.